# Is an asexual person obligated in Pru Urvu?

Tags: halacha, marriage, children-parenting, sexuality, psych-mentalhealth

[Asexuality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asexuality) is a sexual orientation characterized by the lack of sexual attraction towards people in general. Asexuals may or may not be interested in romantic relationships, but are not physically drawn towards sexual activity. They may choose to live celibately, or to participate in sexual activity for practical considerations, so asexuality and celibacy are two very different things.

Is an asexual person obligated in the mitzvah of Pru Urvu despite not experiencing sexual attraction at all? On the one hand mitzvot are normally obligatory even when one does not want to perform them. On the other hand, perhaps the psychological damage that would be incurred by forcing this person to have children would exempt them. Furthermore, perhaps the commandment is contingent on the presence of sexual attraction in the first place, as suggested by an anonymous source [here](http://frumgaygirl.blogspot.com/2013/11/the-good-rav-chassidic-talmud-chacham.html) (the key claim is that "If a person’s psychological infrastructure was such that it didn’t attract him to women, he is not obliged to steel himself and live in a marital relationship in order to have children.").

Comment: Good enough to get my +1 now. Still, do you have any basis to suspect "perhaps the commandment is contingent on the presence of sexual attraction in the first place"?

Comment: found this http://www.bmv.org.il/ab/dd.asp search for brisker. author not orthodox rabbi, but masorti/conservative. talks about gays, but could be applied to asexuals if extent of revulsion is great

Comment: Good question. Still, +0: we need more information about the person you're asking about. 1. Are they married or single? 2. Does their lack of sexual desire cause marked distress or interpersonal difficulty? (If so, it may not be simple "asexuality": it may actually be hypoactive sexual desire disorder or another diagnosable sexual disorder. Possible treatments may include couples therapy, sensate focus therapy, medication, and/or others. Here where I live, health insurance covers all sorts of sexual matters.) 3. Are they reluctant to consult a doctor and to consult a rabbi? 4. If so, why?

Comment: @tealhill I'm not asking about a particular person; this is a hypothetical question. And the question is asking about asexuality, as is explicitly stated, not about hypoactive sexual desire disorder or anything of that sort.

Comment: @Malper: Here, please only ask [practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of the site and push other questions off the front page. Jessamyn [adds](http://metatalk.metafilter.com/17947/Openended-chatty-questions-on-AskMe#662529), "it's okay to ask a sort of philosophical question as long as you explain who you are and why you're asking, what problem of your own you're trying to solve with this information". -1, though if you explain why you asked, I may reconsider.

Comment: @Malper: I spent a fair bit of time doing research towards my first comment. I'm no longer sure I should have done so, considering that the question wasn't even a practical question in the first place.

Comment: There was some [discussion on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164436/162102) about questions asked out of curiosity, with positive results.  We've had other questions that aren't about a problem directly faced by the asker (like, say, about keeping Shabbat in space).  This kind of inquisitiveness is, dare I say, a hallmark of Jewish study and I don't think that alone is reason to reject a question.  As for the issues of individual variation (is this person married vs. single, etc), a good answer would address all the parameters that matter.

Comment: @tealhill, if we understand that to be the standard, then combine that with all questions should not be seeking practical guidance because CYLOR, you can't ask anything on this site. Questions phrased as real actual problems get modified, downvoted and/or closed on this site. So what is left?

Comment: Case in point: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33994/what-do-my-jewish-themed-dreams-mean

Comment: @Yishai:  For better or for worse, people _do_ sometimes ask practical halacha questions on this site instead of asking their LOR.

Comment: This question is based, at least in part, on the supposition that 'psychological damage' would result from this person trying to have children. Is there any evidence to support this or is it just speculation?

Comment: For clarification: is the asexual individual _unable to achieve sexual arousal/stimulation_ or rather one who just doesn't experience sexual attraction? I could see that making a practical difference.

Comment: Unless it is Pikuach Nefesh - it will cause him to be severely depressed or suicide, i can't see why one shouldn't be obligated.

Answer (score 2):

1. I would have thought that every Jewish adult is required to keep the mitzvah of pru urevu. No exeptions made!
2. No-one has the right to inflict harm physical, emotional, or spiritual to anyone else just for the sake of needing to fulfill a requirement.
3. Any g-d fearing person - with the right guidance - can enjoy the fact that he is engaging in a great mitzvah, no less then putting on tefilin which must be done with great simcha [Devorim 28 47]. Many Tzadikim would do what ever they could in order not to have physical benefit from thier physical relationships [see Rashi Bereishis 12 11, Shulchon Oruch OC 240 8], yet they still basked in the enjoyment of engaging in many the great mitzvos they are doing, Vesimach, Onah, Pru Urevu, Sheves.
4. on a practical note, he should check that he is physically able to...
5. obviously as previously mentioned, a visit to a doctor or mental health adviser, would be a good idea.
6. whats the guys name and mothers name so we can daven for him!

Comment: `I would have thought that every Jewish adult is required to keep the mitzvah of pru urevu. No exeptions [sic] made!` This baseless assumed answer is not very valuable.

Comment: To clarify, the OP already noted that there is generally an obligation, but did not consider that sufficient proof. This adds nothing to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it seems he is obligated

Since I did not see any source that relations have to do with his wants

The opposite I see that he is **obligated** to fullfill his [wife's conjugal rights](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.76?lang=bi) even if he is not attached at that time (she has no obligation to seduce him, (but a man can not rape his wife he needs to seduce her if he wants to have relations with her))

And It seem that sometimes it is advisable to marry even an ugly women  (in my understanding without attraction) ([see page 394](http://www.peleyoetz.com/PeleYoetz.aspx?ID=111&t=&Search=))

[And there is no leagal problem to marry a girl you do not want (for other reasons)](http://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.222.1?with=all&lang=bi)

From [Shulchan aruch even ezer 1.3](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.1.3?with=all&lang=bi) it seems that by sefardim thier Bais Din needs to force men to get married even if they do not want to (if a man is forced to make kedushin it is counted)

If I remember correctly that when a wife tries to seduce her husband it is good for him to have relations with her (even if her seduction is not working, he should force himself)

---

The opposite this person is a tzadik his yetser horo does not control him so he can do the mitzvah lishma (just for Hashem (to fullfill his will)) without alternate motives

---

Please explain what psychological damage you are referring to,
to me it seems psychologically healthy to act meaningfully (by fulfill a commandments)

Comment: `Yes it seems he is obligated Since I did not see any source that relations have to do with his wants` לא מצאנו אינו ראיה.

Comment: @mevaqesh so everything is oser until you have a heter? Or it you do not know it is oser you can do it as a reshus, (but probably you need to know the whole Torah before making much decisions)

Comment: @mevaqesh but to be mevatel a positive commandment you need to find a source not the other way

Comment: Perhaps you could claim that if you know a mitsvah exists and you don't know if an exception exists in a particular case you are obligated to act stringently out of doubt. However, you are conflating halakhic-theory, with the burden of proof necessary to answer a question.

Comment: @mevaqesh I think my sources are a good proof, but if you find a source that I am wrong I am ready to take my answer back

Comment: The OP asked `On the one hand mitzvot are normally obligatory even when one does not want to perform them. On the other hand, perhaps the psychological damage that would be incurred by forcing this person to have children would exempt them` That is, he knows that there is generally a mitsvah but wonders whether psychological damage makes a difference. Your source states nothing about psychological damage, and adds nothing to the assumptions already found in the OP.

Comment: `Please explain what psychological damage you are referring to,` Answers should not be used to ask for clarification from the OP. (Those should be relegated to comments),

Comment: @mevaqesh I bring sources with cases that are similar and the philological damage should be similar and still it seems there is a commandment

Comment: your assumption that the `philological [sic] damage should be similar` is totally predicated on the unfounded comparison of a sexual person to an asexual person. Furthermore, you yourself admit that you don't even know what sort of psychological damage is being referred to, to to then make assumptions about it, is simply absurd.

Comment: @mevaqesh that is your opinion, an asexual is a new invention, and from what I understand it is by definition someone who has no attraction to have relations with his wife, I bring sources that not having attraction does not effect the law, (I added another one)

Comment: @mevaqesh i found a source that if a man has relations because of force it does not count for his obligation https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Shmuel.77.4

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, such a person should have a discussion with a mental health professional just to make sure they understand what's going on and how to cope with everything in their life. Similarly, when seriously dating s/he should make clear to a prospective spouse what to expect in this relationship. People can work out all sorts of things. (Maybe he can find a similarly asexual woman and their marriage isn't about physical attraction.)

The rule of thumb is that a person is exempt from a "yes-do" mitzva if it would cost him/her 25% of his/her assets. (E.g. is no woman in the world will marry me unless I pay $100k, and my total net worth is $200k, I'm not expected to get married.) There may be people out there for whom no fulfilling marriage can be found whatsoever, and the psychological toll of an unfulfilling marriage would be equivalent to losing 25% of one's assets, which would prompt this question. I can't make a blanket rule for every individual. It's all a question of how to apply that concept here.

I do think that if such a person spends some time contemplating what they seek in a relationship, finds an appropriate partner, and is open about their expectations, that they could likely make a marriage work without taking a huge toll on themselves (it may even be beneficial) -- that's my guesstimate for most cases.

Comment: If the ongoing cost of marriage and kids counts towards the 25% (as opposed to the immediate cost of the wedding, say) then no one other than the most extremely wealthy is obligated to get married.

Comment: @Yishai Presumably the marital satisfaction that most people get balances it out.

Comment: @Malper, I'm not aware of an exception to that rule based on if you like the Mitzvah. People may choose to do it anyway, but that doesn't create an obligation.

Comment: 1)I'm pretty sure that it is 1/5th i.e. 20% and 2)My teacher, a Rav, cited this general rule specifically with respect the the mitzvah to procreate so if it is worthwhile to discuss it's relevance with your Rav if need be.

Comment: Is there not an idea to spend everything to get married (to a bas talmid hochom)? So maybe marriage is different

Comment: See http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.1.2?with=all&lang=bi

Answer (score -1):

Are w talking about married asexuals, or unmarried? Lemaise, we haven't been concerned about making unmarried people fulfill prvi irvi since, when, centuries at least? The Remu says that we don't.

Married aces, OK. (And yes, there are plenty of them, some of them married to other aces, and some married to sexuals.) If the woman is ace, it should be entirely irrelevant to the halakhic question, because she's anyway not obligated in pri irvi, no?

So the real question is whether an asexual man is obligated in pri irvi, and hey, he's not the one who actually has to physically get pregnant.

So what's the issue, 15 minutes of sex, one or two times, that he might find anything between enjoyable to boring to repulsive (as is the case for plenty of sexuals, of course, in any given act of sex)? Nu? And today there's artificial insemination.

In other words, I think that the questioner doesn't really understand what asexuality is, and is still living with pre-1961 notions that sex and procreation are the same thing.